# Origine et utilisation de « être mitigé » au sein d'une phrase

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, étymologie, orthographe

Lors d'une réponse à la question suivante :

> Et toi, qu'en penses-tu ?

Est-il correct de répondre :

> Je suis **mitigé**.

Est-il grammaticalement correct d'utiliser le terme **mitigé** en Français de nos jours? Ou bien est-ce un abus de langage dû à une mauvaise utilisation de cet adjectif ? Quelle est son étymologie ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cette sorte de transfert de qualité ou d'affectation, qui en tant que qualité ou affectation d'un attribut devient sans modification une qualité ou affectation de la personne toute entière qui possède l'attribut, est souvent admise dans le langage ; en voici un exemple ;

- Je suis opéré demain ; une tumeur doit être enlevée dans mon intestin.

Ce qui est opéré, en vérité, c'est l'intestin, une partie du ventre. On s'aperçoit que ce processus de « transfert » est très courant et il a tendance à étendre ses conquêtes dans le langage. Cependant, il n'est pas universellement applicable, ou disons plutôt appliqué. Il s'agit donc d'une pure question d'usage, d'idiomaticité. Il faut comprendre alors que la grammaire n'est pas en cause ; mis à part l'usage, il ne s'agit que de sémantique.

Dans  le cas de « mitigé », où il s'agit en ce qui concerne l'attribut, par exemple des opinions ou d'une opinion en particulier, non cela ne se dit pas, tout au moins pas traditionnellement ; il se peut cependant qu'il existe un usage naissant, mais il ne peut être que très limité. Cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+suis+mitig%C3%A9%2Cil+est+mitig%C3%A9%2Cnous+sommes+mitig%C3%A9s&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20est%20mitig%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) semble confirmer cela ; il y a quelques cas (on peut citer Madame de Sévigné¹). On peut donc peut être opter pour cette nouvelle forme d'expression, mais on s'engage dans la voie d'une très petite minorité.

Il est toujours correct de dire ceci ;

- Je suis d'un avis mitigé.
- J'ai des opinions mitigées à cet égard.
- Mes sentiments sont mitigés.

Ce qui fait ces assertions préférables c'est qu'elles spécifient un attribut particulier, l'avis, les opinions, les sentiments ; l'interlocuteur situe ainsi tout de suite le domaine d'idée dans lequel considérer la notion conférée par l'adjectif.

Dans l'usage particulier suivant il existe un terme apparenté au processus de transfert dont il est question ci-dessus ;

> [En parlant d'une pers. désignée par son adhésion à un système de pensée] Qui est partisan de l'application ou de l'interprétation modérée d'un système de pensée. Synon. modéré, tiède. À supposer que la synthèse des deux séries de témoignages patristiques déboute de leurs prétentions les agnostiques purs, restera encore la question, soulevée par les **partisans mitigés** du système (Théol. cath. t.4, 1 1920, p.1025).

Le terme « mitigé » est un mot bien établi dans la langue française (un exemple ci-dessous).

- Ses assertions, certainement mitigées en comparaison de celles de son ami, sont quand même révélatrices.

C'est un mot qui vient du latin ;

> Empr. au lat. mitigare «amollir, rendre doux, calmer».

¹<sub>Cependant, il faut savoir que beaucoup de la langue de Madame de Sévigné n'a plus cours de nos jours.</sub>

Comment: Merci pour l'explication !

Answer (score 5):

(Non locuteur natif du français.)

« Mitigé » est toujours courant je crois ; selon cet [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mitig%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmitig%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) du moins. Selon le TLFi (vous pouvez y voir aussi l'étymologie) il existe quelques connotations qui sont obsolètes. En revanche, dans votre contexte, je trouve que *être mitigé* est employé couramment pour signifier (plutôt) défavorable, réservé, dubitatif. Voir [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitig%C3%A9).

**Actualisation**

D'après le lemme du [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_mitig%C3%A9/51817)

> Être plutôt défavorable : Le projet a reçu un accueil très mitigé.
>
> Être relâché, peu rigoureux : Un zèle mitigé.
>
> Être mêlé de quelque
> chose, adouci : Éloges mitigés de critiques.

On lit [ici](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_mitig%C3%A9/51817/difficulte)

> Sens et emploi
>
> Le sens premier de mitigé est « atténué, tempéré,
> devenu ou rendu moins vif ou moins rigide » (le mot vient du latin
> mitis, doux) : « Sa politesse, on l'appelle froideur ; son ironie, si
> mitigée qu'elle soit, méchanceté » (Ch. Baudelaire).
>
> **Dans le registre courant**, le mot est employé aujourd'hui au sens de « mêlé, mélangé,
> qui est à mi-chemin entre deux extrêmes » : éprouver des sentiments
> mitigés. « Quand M. de Guermantes eut terminé la lecture de mon
> article, il m'adressa des compliments, d'ailleurs mitigés » (M.
> Proust).
>
> **recommandation**  Cet emploi est critiqué. Dans l'expression
> soignée, en particulier à l'écrit, on peut remplacer mitigé par
> ambigu, équivoque, mêlé, mélangé, partagé.